# When are canvas updates made in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

I have a JavaScript function which draws on a canvas in Microsoft Edge.  It looks a bit like this

```
function foo() {
    drawSomething(canvas);
    doACalculationThatTakesALongTime();
    drawSomethingElse(canvas);
    doACalculationThatTakesALongTime();
}
```

`foo` is attached as an event handler to some event in my DOM.

The problem that I experience is that the updates to the canvas made by `doACalculationThatTakesALongTime` do not appear until `foo` completes.  Is this to be expected?  By contrast, in Firefox the updates appear immediately.

Comment: When JavaScript is running it takes up the browsers resources until done. This means the browser can't process anything else like rendering until JavaScript releases the thread. To get around this you could wrap `doACalculationThatTakesALongTime` in a `setTimeout`. This means that the JavaScript will release the thread (so it can render the results), wait X milliseconds and then calculate `doACalculationThatTakesALongTime`.

Comment: Thanks @EmilS.Jørgensen.  I'm surprised then that it *does* work OK in Firefox.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: My guess is that Firefox somehow delegates the tasks in a non-linear fashion. Possibly because it is [multi threaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox). This means that even though the main thread is "blocked" by JavaScript, a secondary thread can still use its power to render, whatever is ready. It should be noted that you shouldn't rely on browsers being multi threaded unless you have control over which browser you users will visit your site with. I'm pretty sure most mobile browsers are single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decoupling solution:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawSomething() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, (canvas.width / 3) * 2, (canvas.height / 3) * 2);
}

function drawSomethingElse() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3, (canvas.width / 3) * 2, (canvas.height / 3) * 2);
}

function doACalculationThatTakesALongTime() {
  var d = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - d < 2 * 1000) {}
  console.log("Big calculation done");
}

function foo() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawSomething();
  setTimeout(doACalculationThatTakesALongTime, 1000);
  drawSomethingElse();
  setTimeout(doACalculationThatTakesALongTime, 1000);
}
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Alternatively, if the order of execution is important you can chain these actions together with `Promises` while ensuring frame rendering using `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var p = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));

function drawSomething() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, (canvas.width / 3) * 2, (canvas.height / 3) * 2);
  p.innerHTML += "Drawed something<br>";
}

function drawSomethingElse() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3, (canvas.width / 3) * 2, (canvas.height / 3) * 2);
  p.innerHTML += "Drawed something else<br>";
}

function doACalculationThatTakesALongTime() {
  var d = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - d < 2 * 1000) {}
  p.innerHTML += "Big calculation done<br>";
}

function foo() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        drawSomething();
        resolve();
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          doACalculationThatTakesALongTime();
          resolve();
        });
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          drawSomethingElse();
          resolve();
        });
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          doACalculationThatTakesALongTime();
          resolve();
        });
      });
    })
}
foo();
```

Comment: Thanks, `requestAnimationFrame` was what I needed!